# Machine learning vector association mutually exclusive

Tags: machine-learning, match, classification, shapes, points

I have two sets of vectors representing points in three dimensional space. The first set is strictly smaller than second one. So I pick up all the vectors in the first set and I want to associate each one of them to just one vector from the second set. The association is binjective. So each point from the first set is associated to just one point in the second set, and the points in second set receive just one association each.
My question here is for which kind of algorithm should I use in order to succeed in such a task. I thought of several different approaches but couldn't find the right one.
At first I thought of using cluster assignment . But then I realised that using such an approach doesn't prevent the associations from being multiple ones. clusters might receive eventually more than one point from the first set which is specifically what I don't want to do.
The idea is that I need such an association so that the very shape depicted from the Vectors from the first set resembles the most the overall picture depicted from the Vectors in the second set. It's like as if the vectors from the first set has been subjected to some sort of 3D transformation into the Vectors in the second set but that for some reasons that transformation is recognisable.

Comment: May be an example would be nice!